# Update Column based on other cells

Tags: oracle, date, sql-update, case

would appreciate help with this, as no idea how to even start with this one.

I have a Date column which is sometimes populated, and I want to copy it to all other lines where it isn't populated as long as the Invoice number for that line is the same but lacks the date.

```
Update TableInvoices
Case When InvoiceDate = 0 then Set InvoiceDate to ddmmyyy from InvoiceDate
Where InvoiceNum = InvoiceNum and InvoiceDate <> 0
```

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: A date column can never contain the value `0` so the comparison `When InvoiceDate = 0` makes no sense

Comment: The date is in text form, so is either 21092017 or 0

Comment: Why are you storing a date in a varchar column? That is a bad idea

Comment: No idea, it's an existing DB I've inherited ( I'm not the DBA ) just querying it :-)

Comment: The condition `InvoiceDate = 0 then Set InvoiceDate to ddmmyyy from InvoiceDate` makes no sense. If InvoiceDate is `0` how can you deduct a date from it?

Comment: Where does the ddmmyyy  comes from?

Comment: what does it mean  :  InvoiceNum = InvoiceNum